# How to access dictionary values when key isn't exactly the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, format

### The problem

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {'9.1':'9.7','10.1':'10.7','11.1':'11.7'}
```

And I need to access with values in different format:

```
val_1 = '9.1'
val_2 = '09.1'
```

If val_1 it's easy to get value:

```
>>>print(dic[val_1])
>>>9.7
```

But, in case of val_2 key doesn't exist

Can I use something like this?

```
dic[float(val_2),key = lambda x: float(x) for x in dic.keys()]
```

### Aditional information

Format in dictionary keys could vary.
Examples:

```
dic = {'9':'9.7'}   
dic = {'9.0':'9.7'}
dic = {'09.0':'9.7'}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Whole point of dictionaries (among other things) is that it's keys are known and unique. Handling them without knowing what they are will become a guessing game and you'll need to iterate over every key in order to determine which is the "closest match" defeating the purpose a bit, because lookup times of dictionaries are quite fast as you know the keys. Why don't you know which keys you stuck in there? this feels like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Now that you say it...may be I don't need a dictionary at all. I use it to replace velocities values inside files and in the name of directories, but if I call (and modify) the function that assign values to keys...Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-process your dictionary to have floating point values as keys instead.

Then when you want to access a key, convert to float first.

```
>>> dic = {'9.1':'9.7','10.1':'10.7','11.1':'11.7'}
>>> dic = {float(k):v for k,v in dic.items()}
>>> dic[float("09.1")]
'9.7'
```

Of course this can fail because of floating point precision so it's not really a good idea, but this will work if the various forms of writing the value has just a leading or trailing zero, space, ... so the floating point representation of the value will be exactly the same. In the example with 9 written different ways it would work too:

```
>>> float('09.0') == float('9.0') == float('9')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, you're storing your keys as strings. In that case, the easiest way to remove a leading zero from the `val_2` example would be:

```
val_2.lstrip("0")
```

You can make this method call on strings that *don't* have leading zeros as well, with no side effect. So you could do this:

```
for val in [val_1, val_2]:
    print(dic[val.lstrip("0")])
```

with output:

```
9.7
9.7
```

Comment: you'll have to rstrip 0 and "." too, else 9.0 and 9 aren't the same. `rstrip(".0")` should work